# Lagrange's Form of Remainder using Substitution.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am trying to prove:$$\left|\ln(1+x^2)-\left(x^2-\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^6}{3}\right)\right|\leq x^8$$
Since I already know the taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$ at $x=0$, by substitution, it follows:$$\ln(1+x^2)\approx (x^2)-\frac{(x^2)^2}{2}+\frac{(x^2)^3}{3} + R=x^2-\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^6}{3}+R...$$

How do I find the Lagrange Form of Remainder R?

Comment: Do you know the form of the Lagrange remainder for a generic $f$? Apply it with $f(x)=\log(1+x^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Lagrange Form of Remainder to get the inequality. But it is not necessary. In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\bigg|\ln(1+x^2)-\left(x^2-\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^6}{3}\right)\bigg|\\
&=&2\bigg|\int_0^x\left(\frac{t}{1+t^2}-(t-t^3+t^5)\right)dt\bigg|\\
&=&2\bigg|\int_0^xt\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}-(1-t^2+t^4)\right)dt\bigg|\\
&=&2\bigg|\int_0^xt\frac{1-(1+t^2)(1-t^2+t^4)}{1+t^2}dt\bigg|\\
&=&2\bigg|\int_0^xt\frac{t^6}{1+t^2}dt\bigg|\\
&\le&2\bigg|\int_0^xt^7dx\bigg|\\
&=&\frac14x^8\le x^8.
\end{eqnarray}